# Python library for Amazon MWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Is there a Python library for interacting with [Amazon MWS](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/index.html)? 
I found [Ruby](http://github.com/dmichael/amazon-mws), [Perl](http://github.com/frodwith/Amazon-MWS), [PHP](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/doc/en_US/bde/feeds/v20090901/php.html), [C#](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/doc/en_US/bde/feeds/v20090901/cSharp.html), and [Java](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/doc/en_US/bde/feeds/v20090901/java.html) versions, but not Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

didn't find one so developed my own basic version: http://code.google.com/p/amazon-mws-python/

Comment: If anybody is looking for a newer version, please consider https://github.com/czpython/python-amazon-mws which is based on hoju's basic version - see also @Roman_Bataev's answer.

Comment: The link in the answer seems to be updated to https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/amazon-mws-python

Answer (score 5):

Try [boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/)... I don't think they have MWS yet, but they might add it soon.

UPDATE: Sorry, I mean try making a request to the boto team. Boto seems the be the fullest python library for AWS right now, so it makes sense for them to add it.

Comment: That seems to make it an odd recommendation.

Answer (score 4):

More up-to-date and feature complete version is [here](https://github.com/czpython/python-amazon-mws). As I understand it's based on Richard's original version.

Answer (score 2):

A few can be installed through `pip`.  As of today :

```
$ pip search mws|grep Amazon
fio_amazon_mws          - Amazon MWS Integration
python-amazon-mws       - A python interface for Amazon MWS
openlabs_amazon_mws     - Amazon MWS Integration
amazon-mws              - A python interface for Amazon MWS
```

Looks like `amazon-mws` is hoju's, and `python-amazon-mws` the one quoted by Roman.

The two others are `tryton` modules, not sure how/if they can be used standalone.  `openlabs_amazon_mws` is actually `trytond-amazon-mws`, and `fio_amazon_mws` seems to be a fork.  They both require `python-amazon-mws` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

For python, there's [mws](https://github.com/python-amazon-mws/python-amazon-mws) library.
`pip install mws`

Currently these many features are available in MWS python library,

- List item
  Feeds
- List item
  Inventory
- List item
  InboundShipments
- List item
  Reports
- List item
  Orders
- List item
  Products
- List item
  Recommendations
- List item
  Sellers
- List item
  Finances